# tm package version 0.7 does not preserve intra-word dashes in DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r

The behaviour of the tm package has changed between versions 0.6-2 and 0.7-x.
In the new version, DocumentTermMatrix does not preserve intra-word dashes, is it a bug or is there a new option to enforce that? An example follows below, using both tm versions installed with different paths. I am running R 3.3.3.

```
> string1 <- "big data data analysis machine learning project management"
> string2 <- "big-data data-analysis machine-learning project-management"
> 
> two_strings <- c(string1, string2)
> 
> library("tm", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/tm_0.6-2")
> myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(two_strings))
> dtm_0.6 <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus)
> inspect(dtm_0.6)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2, terms: 11)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 11/11
Sparsity           : 50%
Maximal term length: 18
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs analysis big big-data data data-analysis learning machine machine-learning
   1        1   1        0    2             0        1       1                0
   2        0   0        1    0             1        0       0                1
    Terms
Docs management project project-management
   1          1       1                  0
   2          0       0                  1
```

So with the old version 0.6-2 the dashes in the second string are correctly preserved. With the new version 0.7-3 instead:

```
> detach("package:tm", unload=TRUE)
> library("tm", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/tm_0.7-3")
> dtm_0.7 <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus)
> inspect(dtm_0.7)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2, terms: 7)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 14/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs analysis big data learning machine management project
   1        1   1    2        1       1          1       1
   2        1   1    2        1       1          1       1
```

I tried to enforce the preservation of dashes as follows, but to no avail:

```
> dtm_test <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, 
+            control = list(removePunctuation = list(preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE)))
> inspect(dtm_test)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2, terms: 7)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 14/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs analysis big data learning machine management project
   1        1   1    2        1       1          1       1
   2        1   1    2        1       1          1       1
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from the tm author himself, dr. Ingo Feinerer - thanks! Reproducing it here:

---

Since 0.7 the default corpus is a "SimpleCorpus" (if supported; that
depends on the source). See ?SimpleCorpus

That triggers a certain behavior (see  in ?TermDocumentMatrix).

Use VCorpus instead of Corpus to enforce the old behavior:

inspect(TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(two_strings))))
inspect(TermDocumentMatrix(VCorpus(VectorSource(two_strings))))

---

Returning to my example above, using now VCorpus:

```
> library("tm", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/tm_0.7-3")
> myVCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(two_strings))
> dtm_0.7 <- DocumentTermMatrix(myVCorpus)
> inspect(dtm_0.7)
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2, terms: 11)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 11/11
Sparsity           : 50%
Maximal term length: 18
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs analysis big big-data data data-analysis learning machine machine-learning
   1        1   1        0    2             0        1       1                0
   2        0   0        1    0             1        0       0                1
    Terms
Docs management project
   1          1       1
   2          0       0
```